# How can I have custom CallStyle notification to be non-dismissable on Android 14?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-14

Android 14 forces to use CallStyle to have [non-dismissable notifications](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications):

> This change applies to apps that prevent users from dismissing foreground notifications by setting Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT through Notification.Builder#setOngoing(true) or NotificationCompat.Builder#setOngoing(true). The behavior of FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT has changed to make such notifications actually dismissable by the user.

> This new behavior doesn't apply to notifications in the following use cases:
> CallStyle notifications
> Device policy controller (DPC) and supporting packages for enterprise

I've had a custom style for Android <14 and non-dismissable:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_light)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setFullScreenIntent(setViewNotificationClick(conferenceRoom, member), true)
            .setCustomHeadsUpContentView(notificationLayout)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(getTimeDestroyNotificationPendingIntent(context,conferenceRoom))
            .setTimeoutAfter(30000)
            .build()
```

But now I have to use a premade style to have non-dismissable notifications for incoming calls or ongoing notifications.
How can I access custom decoration style along with non-dismisable notification at the same time?

Comment: what do you mean by they force us? You can use `CallStyle` only in case you develop a phone call application

Comment: @user924 I do want to have a call notification like any internet-based call application, but I don't want to use the `CallStyle` which is not customized.

Comment: It seems that if you are using ```CallStyle```, you cannot use a custom view. I have tried this, and was not able to use my custom view. Probably Android ignores your custom view if you use CallStyle.

I hope, they can put more documentation about this tho.